# HttpRequestException in API call, depending on user

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've been scratching my head about this one for a bit, and I was hoping someone better at parsing error messages might be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a .NET console application which utilizes the Dropbox API. The affected code snippet is printed below. When I run the executable from **my** machine (in a folder, co-located with the Dropbox DLL) it connects fine and performs some lookup as intended. When another user on the same network runs it on their machine (similar settings), the HttpRequestException printed below is logged after 20 seconds (consistently). Additionally, if I wrap this as a service for testing and run it on a third machine, it runs as expected under my account user/pass, but logs the same error when run under another user/pass.

Can anyone with better eyes at parsing error messages help steer me toward the solution? Or does anyone have ideas as to what I might be missing? I appreciate any help, even shots in the dark.

```
    var _AccessToken = [value]
    //DropboxCertHelper.InitializeCertPinning();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler { ReadWriteTimeout = 10000 })
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
    };

    try
    {
        var config = new DropboxClientConfig("MyApplication")
        {
            HttpClient = httpClient
        };

        var client = new DropboxClient(_AccessToken, config);
        ListFolderResult listing = new ListFolderResult();
        listing = await client.Files.ListFolderAsync(_AppPath, true);

        foreach (var item in listing.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFolder))
        {
            Log(item.PathDisplay);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log(e);
    }
```

And this is the logged error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
    ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 162.125.7.7:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.<RequestJsonString>d__2f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.<RequestJsonStringWithRetry>d__1a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.<Dropbox.Api.Stone.ITransport.SendRpcRequestAsync>d__5`3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyApplication.Program.<MyMethod>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I believe it is not something to do with the code but with the access token. The access token is generated for you own dropbox account and this access token cannot be reused in someone else's machine. If you want to verify, you can create another drop box access token for the user you want to test and try that access token in there machine.

Comment: For things like this I use fiddler or postman and check if I can send a request through that. Once I am able to then I write code. If something goes wrong, I know its my code so that helps. Nonetheless the error seems to be due to connection not being made. Perhaps an authentication issue or something.

Comment: I doubt that it is about the access token since it clearly says that the connection to a specific host:ip failed. Maybe the access in the network is restricted and access through the firewall is allowed for you but not for others. Or a proxy is configured for your account but not for others.

Comment: Are you trying to make the Http call from behind some proxy? If yes try adding <defaultProxy> in config file.

Comment: This does not appear to be an issue with the access token itself. The error message indicates that the app was not able to connect to the server, so there wasn't a chance to use the access token yet anyway. I agree that it appears to be a networking issue, e.g., some proxy or firewall interfering.

Comment: Steffen & Greg, After some additional research and tests with an invalid token, I definitely agree that the issue doesn't appear related to the access token. I was also able to run the application from home last night as another test. I am not well-versed in networking internals, but I am told the firewall settings should be similar. So it seems I will have to do some research on Proxys. Does it make sense that, for instance, wrapping it as a service and running with my log/pass has no issue, but a different log/pass could potentially run afoul of a proxy?

Comment: After further research, this may be a firewall issue after all. I appreciate the responses you all provided. It helped to steer me in the direction of inquiry.